# Python: How to create a function that uses its own output and uses an array of random generated numbers

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x

Disclaimer: I am quite new to Python and programming as a whole.

I have been trying to create a function to generated random stock prices using the following:

```
New stock price = previous price + (previous price*(return + (volatility * random number)))
```

The `return and volatility` numbers are fixed. Also, I have generated the random numbers for N times.

*The problem is how to create a function that has the output re-used again on itself as an input `previous price`.*

*Basically to have an array of NEW stock prices generated from this formula and the `previous price` variable is the output of the function on itself.*

I have been trying to do this for a couple of days and I am sure I am not fully equipped to do it (given that I am a newbie) but ANY HELP would really really be more than appreciated...!!!

Please any help would be useful.

---

```
import random

initial_price = 10
return_daily = 0.12 / 252
vol_daily = 0.30 / (math.sqrt(252))


random_numbers = []
for i in range (5):
    random_numbers.append(random.gauss(0,1))

 def stock_prices(random_numbers):
    prices = []
    for i in range(0,len(random_numbers)):
        calc = initial_price + (initial_price * (return_daily+(vol_daily*random_numbers[i])))
        prices.append(calc)
    return prices
```

Comment: I'm not sure whether you mean a really simple question ("*how do I store the prices and put them through a function?*") or a deeper question ("*I want to update the prices with this function several times and then stop, how can I redo the function over itself?*") or a more involved question ("*I need the function output re-used again on itself  as an input because this is something involving recursion, and making the function call itself is significant, how can it call itself?*"). Can you explain more, ideally posting some code?

Comment: Hi, Sorry for the confusion. I am quite new to this but I really appreciate the feedback as its all leading to learning. The point I want mainly is ""I need the function output re-used again on itself as an input because this is something involving recursion, and making the function call itself is significant, how can it call itself?". And the outputs, one-by-one, to be added to an array/list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't really use recursion here, because you don't have a break condition that ends the recursion. You could construct one by passing an additional counter parameter that specifies how many more levels to recurse, but that would be not optimal in my opinion.

Instead, I recommend you to use a for loop that gets repeated a fixed number of times you can specify. This way you can add one new price value to a list per loop iteration step and access the previous one to calculate it:

```
first_price = 100
list_length = 20

def price_formula(previous_price):
    return previous_price * 1.2  # you would replace this with your actual calculation

prices = [first_price]  # create list with initial item
for i in range(list_length):  # repeats exactly 'list_length' times, turn number is 'i'
    prices.append(price_formula(prices[-1]))  # append new price to list
    # prices[-1] always returns the last element of the list, i.e. the previously added one.

print("\n".join(map(str, prices)))
```

---

My optimization of your code snippet:

```
import random

initial_price = 10
return_daily = 0.12 / 252
vol_daily = 0.30 / (math.sqrt(252))

def stock_prices(number_of_prices):
    prices = [initial_price]
    for i in range(0, number_of_prices):
        prices.append(prices[-1] + (prices[-1] * (return_daily+(vol_daily*random.gauss(0,1))))
    return prices
```

Comment: Please edit your question to add that code sample, it's not well readable in the comments. You may notify me once you've done that. Also please consider accepting this answer if it solves your problem.

Comment: @KSoliman No, you can't do it like that. You're always reusing the first value instead of the previous one. Also, I see no need to store the random values and use two loops, so I converted it into one loop. See my edited answer.

Comment: ....Thank you So much. The loop works more than perfect! I really appreciate the feedback.

Comment: @KSoliman In this case please accept the answer, as it seems to have solved your problem. Do that by clicking on the grey check symbol on its left. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is the classic Markov process. The present value depends upon its previous value, and only its previous value. The best thing to use in this case is what is called an iterator. Iterators can be created to generate arbitrary iterators that model the markov model.

Learn about how iterators can be generated here http://anandology.com/python-practice-book/iterators.html

Now that you have some understanding of how iterators work, you can create your own iterators for your problem. You need a class that implements the `__iter__()` method and the `next()` method.

Something like this:

```
import random
from math import sqrt

class Abc:

    def __init__(self, initPrice):

        self.v = initPrice # This is the initial price
        self.dailyRet  = 0.12/252
        self.dailyVol = 0.3/sqrt(252)
        return

    def __iter__(self): return self

    def next(self):
        self.v += self.v * (self.dailyRet + self.dailyVol*random.gauss(0,1) )
        return self.v


if __name__ == '__main__':

    initPrice = 10
    temp = Abc(initPrice)

    for i in range(10):
        print temp.next()
```

This will give the output:

```
> python test.py
10.3035353791
10.3321905359
10.3963790497
10.5354048937
10.6345509793
10.2598381299
10.3336476153
10.6495914319
10.7915999185
10.6669136891
```

Note that this *does not* have the stop iteration command, so if you use this incorrectly, you may get into trouble. However, that is not difficult to implement and I hope you try to implement it ...

Comment: Thank you so much for your feedback. This has a million times learning experience (considering I am a newb to this). I really appreciate your help on this =)...